# R extension on RapidMiner

Tags: r, rapidminer

I have installed rJava in R and the next step is to configure RapidMiner such that it can incorporate the R extension...The variables are set as:

R_HOME=/home/.../R-2.12.2
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre

I have exported both of these to PATH as well as $R_HOME/bin in which I also copied the libR.so file which was originally in $R_HOME/lib

However when I try to configure RapidMiner with: java -jar rapidminer.jre
I am getting the following message in a window:

> R extension could not be initialized. Error while loading native R library. Please check PATH, R_HOME and JAVA_HOME environment variable settings.
>
> Reason:
>   /home/username/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/2.12/rJava/jri/libjri.so: liR.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The file /home/username/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/2.12/rJava/jri/libjri.so is definitely there...I have no idea what to do...please help!

I am running a 64-bit Ubuntu.

PS: I read in some posts that I should change my JAVA_HOME to $RAPIDMINER_HOME/jre, but there is no jre directory in my $RAPIDMINER home

> UPDATE: I reinstalled R and rJava again and before that I deleted a .RapidMiner5 file from my home and rebuilt the rapidminer directory again...this time when I start rapidminer.jar it doesn't show any error messages, instead it starts as if rJava has not been installed at all and shows no reaction!

Comment: I had trouble with rJava while configuring it for Rbbg, can you try `Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="")` and see if it works, it solved my problem with Rbbg

Comment: I tried, but no solution :(

Answer (score 0):

Question: Is your version of Rapidminer also 64bit? All the bit architectures for Rapidminer, R, and Java have to be same for Rapidminer/R extension to run.

Comment: I downloaded the R source for R-2.12.2 from CRAN, but I am being unable to check exactly what my bit architecture for R is...I have been trying for some time, but got no clue yet...
Same goes for my Rapidminer which I downloaded from Sourceforge

Please give me any pointers to how I can determine what the respective architectures are...I know my Java is 64-bit.

Comment: I think my R is 64 bit since the installation of rJava from inside R created the directory "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library"...but not sure if that's a correct indication

Comment: Ok my R is definitely 64 bit...tried out .Machine$sizeof.pointer and it returned 8 which indicates it's a 64-bit R.
Any clues how I might check the rapidminer architecture?

Comment: There is a file on sourceforge for 64bit Rapidminer, its: rapidminer-5.3.013x64-install.exe.  Did you d/l that one?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu, so I didn't download the exe file...The file I downloaded was rapidminer-5.3.013.zip from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/rapidminer/files/1.%20RapidMiner/5.3/